# communicate with a container created with docker-compose

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose

i have macOS 11.5, docker desktop 4.10, microservices with spring boot.
I use docker-compose to allow me to start my microservices.
A portion of docker-compose:

```
authentication-server:
     build: ./authentication-server
     network_mode: "host"
     image: authentication-server: 0.0.9
     hostname: authentication-srv
     ports:
      - "4445:4445"
```

basically I need to communicate with the container, interrogating it from my pc using Postman, then a REST request.

Despite the nerwork_mode: "host" when I try to ping localhost: 4445 it tells me

"ping: cannot resolve localhost: 4445: Unknown host".

As well as trying the various container names:

"ping: cannot resolve authentication-srv: 4445: Unknown host"

"ping: cannot resolve authentication-server: 4445: Unknown host"

So my need is to communicate with a container created with docker-compose on my local pc. How can I solve? thank you

Comment: Why are you using 'ping' to determine if you can connect? If you are intending to use Postman then you are presumably talking to a HTTP-based server on the container and so you should use ``curl`` or ``wget`` or similar to test that you can connect. The hostname ``authentication-srv`` will not resolve on your host - that is the name within the docker network - so you should be trying to connect to the port on ``localhost`` or perhaps your actual host name.

Comment: Host networking does not work in Docker Desktop (on any platform) and is almost never necessary; you should delete the `network_mode: host` option.  ping(1) is a very-low-level diagnostic tool that sends ICMP ECHO packets, and it doesn't know about things like TCP ports; it's usually not the right tool, prefer something like Curl for HTTP debugging.

Comment: If I remove the `network_mode:host` docker will use its own bridge type network by default and I don't know how to connect to the containers.